# How to check if one can enter Singapore

Tags: paperwork, singapore, malaysian-citizens

I've been working in Singapore for 9-10 years. For my last year, ending my work permit, I just left my company and went back to Johor Bharu. They already cancelled my permit, but I haven't returned my work permit to the company, and it's been 2 years now.

If I'm going to enter Singapore again, will I be blacklisted? I'm scared because my last company said they already built a case for me. The operation manager sent me an email that I've been dismissed, and a case number to deal with the police. They didnt give me my salary for the full month, they said to pay something, and theres no Immigration Officer or any land line police number calling me. I did a text message from an Immigration Officer asking me to come and talk.

I haven't tried to enter Singapore. Am I in trouble? How can I check if I have a case report in Singapore? What should I do about not returning my work permit card?

Comment: I think this would do better on Expatriates since it's about going to Singapore to work, not for a quick visit. I'm going to tidy it up then vote to close.

Comment: So, you had a job, left it, and went home. Why are the police involved? Why do you think you might be blacklisted?

Comment: According to https://www.mom.gov.sg/passes-and-permits/work-permit-for-foreign-worker/cancel-a-work-permit the employer must return the original Work Permit card within 1 week from the cancellation by posting it to Work Pass Division, Ministry of Manpower, 18 Havelock Road, Singapore 059764. They can use the WP Online’s "card return" function to advise why they are unable to return the card. Assuming your employer did this, you could post the permit to the MOM yourself

Answer (score 2):

From an Immigration point of view, you left Singapore before the expiry of your permit, so you should be in the clear.  You can return the physical card at a Singapore high commission (by mail is OK), but not returning it is not a crime or anything.

Where you *may* have trouble, though, is tax clearance: all your outstanding taxes need to be deducted from your last pay.  It sounds like your company may have done this, but it would be advisable to check with IRAS and see if you owe them anything.

I have no idea what's up with the "police case" etc, but assuming you haven't committed any actual crimes, this may be just some sort of scare tactic.  Did your contract have clauses about requiring payment in lieu of notice etc?  Even if yes, this is a civil matter, the police will not get involved.